# Faster or quicker detection of Control Identifier with Pywinauto for Desktop/Windows application

Tags: python, windows, pywinauto

How to make control id detection quick with pywinauto?

I have tried with using different functions of pywinauto viz. "Pywinauto.Desktop" to get active window and search control id it it or by using "Pywinauto.findwindows". Still no luck.
I want to perform click operation on particular control ids. Time for this execution is varying 3 to 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using low level functions directly since you may not aware about all necessary parameters for them.

But there are several hints that can speed your code up. Please look into this discussion: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/256

P.S. The question is a little bit common (ask for recommendation) and typically should be closed. Hope the thread on GitHub will solve the most common issues on this way.